# Tensorflow Adding Decaying Gaussian Noise to Inputs with Lambda Function

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, lambda, noise

I am trying to add gaussian noise to my inputs that decays over the time. One obvious way is to generate noise, based on the current epoch, before I feed my inputs into my model. For example:

```
for i in range(1, epochs+1):
    # Generating noise that decays over the time.
    noise = tf.random.normal(shape=inputs.shape, mean=0.0, stddev=1/i)

    # Adding the noise to inputs.
    inputs += noise

    model.train_on_batch(inputs, targets)
```

However, I recently discovered that tensorflow already comes with a GaussianNoise layer:

```
tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(
     stddev, **kwargs
)
```

But it seems that stddev value is fixed. Is there any way to add a lambda function to stddev argument? For example something like this:

```
def get_stddev(i, max_epochs):
     return i / max_epochs

i = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(GaussianNoise(stddev=lambda: get_stddev(i, 50)))
...
...
return model
```

And during the training:

```
for i in range(1, 50):
    model.train_on_batch(inputs, targets)
```

While the model compiles, tensorflow compains at the beginning of the training that the gaussian noise layer expected a tf.Float32 but got lambda function instead. Is there any way I could do this alternatively?

Thanks in advance